# Mark an area within a plot in Jupyter Notebook and extract the data/ brushing

Tags: python, plot, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, interactive

We are using Jupyter Notebooks and would like to make our graphical data analysis more interactive: we would like to select an area
in a plot and be able to easly access/ extract the data. We saw that you can do such things with e.g. bokeh. However, we are searching for something "simpler", just a few python code lines any scripting beginners can grasp easily.

We feel that others probably solved this issue many times and we just don't know the right buzz words for searching.
Can you help us searching?

Again, marking and data extracting is the main goal. Additional stretch goals would be:

- If you mark some data in one plot, they should also marked in all other plots.
- We could use seaborn for plotting.

Thank you in advance and best regards.